# Disabling Openlayers map in GeoDjango Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, maps, geodjango

I'm using Django 1.6 with Postgres/PostGIS (GeoDjango). I noticed when I upgraded from 1.5 to 1.6 that I am no longer able to add spatial data using WKT through the admin page. Previously, I could paste in the WKT of the geometry that I wanted to display into a text box. Now, when I go to the admin page, a map is displayed which does allow me to edit the geometry, but I cannot add data.

Is there a simple fix that allows me to disable showing this map?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can override the widget used in any admin form with **formfield_overrides**.

from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides

> **ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides**
>
> This provides a quick-and-dirty way to override some of the Field options for use in the admin. formfield_overrides is a dictionary mapping a field class to a dict of arguments to pass to the field at construction time.

So in your case, you'd want to override the lovely open layers map with a plain old text field. The following would replace the maps with a text input for any PointField in the GeoModel model.

```
from app.models import GeoModel
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class DirectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.PointField: {'widget': TextInput }
    }

admin.site.register(GeoModel, DirectAdmin)
```

You might find a Textarea makes reading the WKT a lot easier, so change the second import to:

```
from django.forms.widgets import Textarea
```

And use that in the override instead of the TextInput:

```
models.PointField: {'widget': Textarea }
```

Comment: Thanks, the lovely OpenLayers map is no-more! Is it possible to make the box bigger such that you can see a block of text? For example, some of the WKT I paste in is quite long - it would be nice to see it all.

Comment: Great, glad that did the trick. The simplest thing would be to change it to a Textarea, I'll edit the answer to show that.

Comment: Having trouble with this in django 2.0, it doesn't seem to be overriding the PointField or PolygonField items.... Confirmed that standard CharField is getting properly overwritten.  Any known changes that would affect doing this?

Comment: Be sure that you inherit from django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin and not django.contrib.gis.admin.OSMGeoAdmin I've made the same mistake.